# Embed document without knowing _id in Mongoose/Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know there are no "joins" in MongoDB. I'm attempting to link a large number of documents to the 40,000+ locations in my locations collection.

My locations collection has custom (read: not under my control) identifiers for locations and their corresponding lat/lng coordinates.

```
var Locations = new Schema({
    location_id: String, 
    loc: { //lng, lat: as per mongodb documents
         type: [Number], 
         index: '2d'
    } 
});
```

There are several collections that have a field referencing this custom identifier to match latitude and longitude.

```
var MyCollection = new Schema({
    location: String,
    otherFields: Strings...
});
```

I'm a little lost on how to best go about this. A lot of posts suggest linking via Schema, but I've only seen that with an `Schema.Types.ObjectId`. This seems impractical for me because the data I'm importing only have the custom identifier.

Could I perhaps add another field into `MyCollection` and find the correct `_id` of the location to link to while I'm uploading data. If so, can someone point me in the right direction for accomplishing this.

Map reduce could be used somehow perhaps? I'm still a bit novice with Mongo.

**Tried**

I did try loading up the entirety of the location data into a JS object then checking that object against the return object from my other query, injecting the matching location data into my return object. This works but is ***unbearably*** slow.

Comment: Mongoose will internally do two separate queries anyway, so i'd say just go that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just for the record: MongoDb will still generate an *_id* property for each object you store.

```
1. "[...], if the mongod receives a document to insert that does not contain an _id field, mongod will add the _id field that holds an ObjectId. [...]"
```

[Source](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/)

You wrote that *location_id* is not under your control. And you want to use *location_id* because the other collections are using it also? So you don't want to break the standard in your project which is good.

As I see, you already have the *location* property in *MyCollection* and can store the *location_id* there.
As far as I know, you have to write your own linking methods now. You  have to store the location_id in MyCollection and load the Location if you want to access if via MyCollection by

```
Locations.find({location_id: <the_location_id>})
```

But maybe your main problem is that you cannot find the *Locations* you are looking for in a reliable time?

I don't know your criteria for finding *Locations* for *MyCollection* is. If it is proximity of coordinates then you can reduce the amount of locations to check by filtering out the ones you really don't need to check. Then you don't have to check all the 40.000 Locations, but maybe just 100? In the following I assume it is the proximity.

Do you have *lat, lon* in both collections (*Locations*, *MyCollection*) ?
If so, you can define a query which gets locations around your *MyCollection* object (square). Then you will receive a smaller amount of *Locations* from MongoDb. Now you can apply your more complex check which checks if they really belong to your *MyCollection*-object.

something like this:

```
Locations.find({lat: {$gt: <x>-a, $lt: <x>+a}, lon: {$gt: <y>-b, $lt: <y>+b}}, function(locations){ ... });
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Shouldn't have posted this right before the holiday lol. So, my thoughts on this is to do the find for the locations first, then put those `location_id`s in an array and use it in a following `$in` query on my other collection, assuring that I only get ones I'm looking for. I still have to merge those two object afterwards, but that should be faster. I'll try now and get back to you ASAP.